# Global variables in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, global-variables

How do I declare global variables in Visual C#?

Comment: You creating ASP.NET web page or Windows Form Application?
If ASP.NET - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797332/creating-global-variables-in-asp-net-using-c .
If Form App - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-winforms-global-variables

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this

```
public static class Globals {
    public static int GlobalInt { get; set; }
}
```

Just be aware this isn't thread safe. Access like `Globals.GlobalInt`

This is probably another discussion, but in general globals aren't really needed in traditional OO development. I would take a step back and look at why you think you need a global variable. There might be a better design.

Comment: In what sense is it not thread safe? And how is that any different from a non-static property?

Comment: -1 for not explaining why it isn't thread safe... needs more explanation

Comment: This isn't a question about thread safety. If you are interested in thread safety then ask in another question or update this question to explicitly include a thread safe solution. Also see this question for what thread safety is if you never heard the term http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code

Comment: +1 for "I would take a step back and look at why you think you need a global variable. There might be a better design." 

I found in large projects, it is a lot more difficult to track the use of global variables opposed to instance variables. This helps, especially during maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

A public static field is probably the closest you will get to a global variable

```
public static class Globals
{
  public static int MyGlobalVar = 42;
}
```

However, you should try to avoid using global variables as much as possible as it will complicate your program and make things like automated testing harder to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Use the const keyword:

```
public const int MAXIMUM_CACHE_SIZE = 100;
```

Put it in a static class eg

```
public class Globals
{
    public const int MAXIMUM_CACHE_SIZE = 100;
}
```

And you have a global variable class :)

Comment: Doesn't the const keyword make it constant?  Can it be changed?

Comment: "The const keyword is used to modify a declaration of a field or local variable. It specifies that the value of the field or the local variable cannot be modified." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: A const field isn't varable. ;)

Comment: lol yeah - i read the question too quickly, I usually only provide contants when exposing values globally.  Everything else are in instance variables. :)

Answer (score 1):

The nearest you can do this in C# is to declare a public variable in a public static class.  But even then, you have to ensure the namespace is imported, and you specify the class name when using it.