# Is it possible to have a "var" as a Global variable

Tags: c#

I have noticed there are other threads on global variables in c#. Such as integers, strings etc. e.g.

```
public static int;
```

But I need to use a "var" which the other thread don't mention and

```
public static var;
```

doesn't seem to work.

So what I'm asking is it possible to have a "var" as a global variable in c#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043302/possible-to-make-a-global-var-c-sharp

Comment: are you familiar with static read-only variables or properties or protected static declaration..? I feel a `CLOSE` coming on here with this question

Comment: var is a C# keyword, can't use it as a name. Global variables = bad idea

Comment: `var` is *not* a type. The type of the variable is inferred at compile time from the declaration, that's why you have to immediately assign a value to it and can't use it to declare class members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx) (section 26.1) reads:

> [`var is] an implicitly typed local variable declaration ...

It goes further:

> A local variable declarator in an implicitly typed local variable
> declaration is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The declarator must include an initializer.
> - The initializer must be an expression.
> - The initializer expression must have a compile-time type which cannot
>   be the null type.
> - The local variable declaration cannot include
>   multiple declarators.
> - The initializer cannot refer to the declared variable itself

So no, you cannot do this. Moreover I would recommend steering away from even thinking about global variables.

Global variables are not supported by the language. You may find alternatives in `public static` fields, but this will leak object state and break encapsulation.

Comment: Can you please give us a further reading on why to steer away from global variables inside of a class? I'm a developer with 4 years experience and I always use it knowing I shouldn't but I can't think of something different most of the time. Time to change the habits and the theory starting from the root I guess.

Comment: @BarryGuvenkaya It depends on what you understand under global variable. In a context of this question, I think OP wanted to use `var` keyword for his variable. When I said global I meant *public member of a class*. Following encapsulation principle, members of a class should be private so no to leak implementation details and state of a class. If you want to use class as a data transfer object or you simply want to get its current state you can always use *public properties*. Does it make sense?

Comment: That clears up sir thank you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

No, because var is not a type itself, it merely takes on the form of whatever expression is on the righthand side of the assignment:

```
var num = 1;
```

is the same as:

```
int num = 1;
```

when declaring variables that are scoped outside of a method, you need to use the full type designator:

```
public static int num = 1;
```

or

```
public static int Num {get;set;}
```

etc

Comment: "When declaring variables that are scoped outside of a method, you need to use the full type designator"...Can you explain why so???