# Make a global variable from var

Tags: c#

In a C# method I Had:

```
 var followers = user.GetFollowers(250);
 var friends = user.GetFriends(250);
 var favorites = user.GetFavorites(40);
```

How can I make these variables accessible to other methods, within my Windows Form App?

I have tried:

```
 private string followers = user.GetFollowers(250);
 private string friends = user.GetFriends(250);
 private string favorites = user.GetFavorites(40);
```

And:

```
private followers = user.GetFollowers(250);
private friends = user.GetFriends(250);
private favorites = user.GetFavorites(40);
```

I have tried putting the above examples, right at the top of my code, but this does not work. What could I be doing wrong. I'm new to programming.

Comment: where is the other method?

Comment: Do you have access to the fields or are they empty? can you post your class

Comment: The method would be: `code` capture() { var favorites = user.GetFavorites(40); foreach (fav in Favorites) {fav.text} } `code`

Comment: I would like variable favourites with its info (user.GetFollowers(250);)  to be accessible throughout my program.

Comment: So i dont have to repeat var favorites1 = user.GetFavorites(40); var favorites2 = user.GetFavorites(40); var favorites3 = user.GetFavorites(40); for every new method that uses favorites

Comment: what is the return type of GetFavorites

Comment: Since your question is so _very_ basic about object orientated programming, i'd suggest you read some basic literature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a "var" as a Global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572690/is-it-possible-to-have-a-var-as-a-global-variable)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: https://twitter.com/ExpertBeginner1/status/578612657835507712

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what the return type of the `user.GetFollowers(int i)` is.
And in what context is `user` defined?

You seem to be a bit confused about the basics of C#.
`private` is simply specifying that you cannot access your member outside the context of your class. It is not a data-type. 
See this question for more info about access-modifiers as they are called
[What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-nothing)

The keyword `var` is just compliler-magic, and cannot be used for properties or other members of a class.

To implement a member of class (be it a field, property or method) you must know the return-type.

In your case; the easiest way to get it is just to see what `user.GetFollowers(int i)` returns, the fastest way to do this is to simply browse to it by putting your cursor on it and go to it by pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> key in visual studio.

You have tagged your question with [tweetinvi](/questions/tagged/tweetinvi) so I'm going to assume this has something to do with twitter.

For this example, i will just call the unknown types `FriendCollection`, `FollowerCollection` and `FavoriteCollection`. Since "GetFriends" seems to suggest that it will return some sort of collection.

```
public class TwitterUserInfo
{
    public FriendCollection Friends { get; get; }
    public FollowerCollection Followers { get; set; }
    public FavoriteCollection Favorites { get; set; }

    public TwitterUserInfo(TwitterUser user)
    {
        Friends = user.GetFriends(20);
        Followers = user.GetFollowers(20);
        Favorites = user.GetFavorites(20);
    }
}
```

You can then use it as such:

```
TwitterUserInfo userInfo = new TwitterUserInfo(someTwitterUser);
```

And the "userInfo" will then contain the properties you want. for example `userInfo.Friends` will contain the friends.

Since you have not provided much information about what is going on, i cannot give a more elaborate answer.

*EDIT: Cleared up a few things*