# How to use variables set globally in a method C#

Tags: c#, variables

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

}

static class Questions
{
    public static var contents = File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFile/Questions.txt");
    public static var newRandom = new Random();
    public static var randomLine = newRandom.Next(0, contents.Length - 1);
    public static var questionToAsk = contents[randomLine];
}
```

But it dives me the following error:

> the contexual keyword 'var' ....

The variable questionToAsk has a random line from a textfile and it gets set. But when I try to access it from the SomeOther method. I can not call it.

What is a way around this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: those aren't declared globally.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw what do you mean? the SomeOther is a class? basically SomeOther is a timer elapsed method and I don't want to set a new question every second of the tick. I hope you understand what I mean..

Comment: @IamThe6 Currently the "SomeOther" method is not inside a class, that's what I mean. nevertheless, you'll need to declare the "questionToAsk" globally.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw okay how do i make it global? I tried using static class but got error. please see edits//

Comment: you can't use a var as a public static.  it needs to be declared by type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572690/is-it-possible-to-have-a-var-as-a-global-variable/14572722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `var` you cannot use them to define fields and properties, you can use them to define implicitly typed local variables. you should change the class definition like this:

```
static class Questions
{
    public static string[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFile/Questions.txt");
    public static Random newRandom = new Random();
    public static string questionToAsk = String.Empty // Will set it later
}
```

So you can access those variables by using the class name, `Questions` like the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int randomLine = Questions.newRandom.Next(0, contents.Length - 1);
    Questions.questionToAsk = Questions.contents[randomLine]; 
}
```

So you have three static variables under the class `Questions` you can access those variables anywhere in the application by using `Questions`.`variable_name`.